# Breakpoints in Chrome set in a workspace file are shown but don't break

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on local files in 37.0.2042 canary so I have the source directory in my workspace with the source html file which contains some simple javascript. When I go to that file in the browser, there are two copies of the file shown in the sources window, one which  seems to be what the browser is currently executing, the other the workspace accessed file.

Devtools lets me put a breakpoint into the workspace file, however it will never break on it. Placing a breakpoint on exactly the same place using the other displayed copy of the file breaks correctly.

This may be the desired behavior, however it is quite mysterious. Or am I missing something?